# Как заполнить таблицу с помощью ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

Здравствуйте! Использую DataTables и ajax-запросом хочу отобразить таблицу, передав данные в json.

Метод контроллера, который возвращает json:

```
public string GroupReportPartial()
    {
        using (AcademicProgressDb db = new AcademicProgressDb())
        {
            var query = (from Students in db.Students
                         from StudentsSubjects in db.StudentsSubjects
                         from Subjects in db.Subjects
                         from ControlPeriods in db.ControlPeriods
                         from ControlTypes in db.ControlTypes

                         where
                           Students.RecordBookNumber == StudentsSubjects.StId.ToString()
                         where
                         Subjects.SubjectId == StudentsSubjects.SubjId
                         where
                         ControlPeriods.ControlPeriodId == StudentsSubjects.CtrlPeriodId
                         where
                         ControlTypes.ControlTypeId == StudentsSubjects.CtrlTypeId
                         select new GroupsReportModel
                         {
                             StudentGroupNumber = Students.GroupNumber,
                             StudentLastName = Students.LastName,
                             StudentFirstName = Students.FirstName,
                             StudentMiddleName = Students.MiddleName,
                             SubjectName = Subjects.Name,
                             ControlPeriodName = ControlPeriods.Name,
                             ControlTypeName = ControlTypes.Name
                         }).ToList();

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
        }
    }
```

Работает успешно. В результате я получаю:

```
[{"StudentGroupNumber": 2012,"StudentLastName": "Глобчук","StudentFirstName": "Даниил","StudentMiddleName": "Владимирович","SubjectName": "Иностранный язык","ControlPeriodName": "Второй семестр","ControlTypeName": "Зачет"}]
```

Код в представлении:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#example').DataTable({
           ajax: {
               url: '@Url.Action("GroupReportPartial")',
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               dataSrc: "",
               columns: [
                    { data: "StudentGroupNumber", name:"StudentGroupNumber" },
                    { data: "StudentLastName", name: "StudentLastName" },
                    { data: "StudentFirstName", name: "StudentFirstName" },
                    { data: "StudentMiddleName", name: "StudentMiddleName" },
                    { data: "SubjectName", name: "SubjectName" },
                    { data: "ControlPeriodName", name: "ControlPeriodName" },
                    { data: "ControlTypeName", name: "ControlTypeName" }
               ]
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>StudentGroupNumber</th>
            <th>StudentLastName</th>
            <th>StudentFirstName</th>
            <th>StudentMiddleName.</th>
            <th>SubjectName</th>
            <th>ControlPeriodName</th>
            <th>ControlTypeName</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Казалось бы всё хорошо, но получаю ошибку

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

Количество столбцов в json и во view одинаковое. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: У Вас метод HttpGet в контроллере указан, а в Ajax запросе Вы используете HttpPost. Вам приходит ответ от сервера правильный. Посмотрите лог запросов на сервер в debug. Если нет - измените метод и посмотрим, что еще не так.

Comment: @sombik, "посмотрим, что еще нет так". К счастью, я уже решил вопрос 2 года назад и ответил на него сам же. Не понимаю смысл Вашего комментария.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моя ошибка из-за невнимательности. Разместил параметр `columns` внутри параметра `ajax`, а надо было вне его.

Правильный код рабочего скрипта:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (data) {
       $('#example').DataTable({
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           ajax: {
               url: '@Url.Action("GroupReportPartial")',
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               dataSrc: ""
           },
           columns: [
               { data: "StudentGroupNumber", name: "StudentGroupNumber" },
               { data: "StudentLastName", name: "StudentLastName" },
               { data: "StudentFirstName", name: "StudentFirstName" },
               { data: "StudentMiddleName", name: "StudentMiddleName" },
               { data: "SubjectName", name: "SubjectName" },
               { data: "ControlPeriodName", name: "ControlPeriodName" },
               { data: "ControlTypeName", name: "ControlTypeName" }
           ]

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял , твои данные (JSON) не доходят до функции . Попробуй  $(document).ready(function (data) {...});

Comment: так вроде бы так и пишу =)

Comment: пардон, не заметил параметра

Comment: Всё равно та же ошибка, не помогло